# Flask-SQLAlchemy Query records by relationship attribute

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In the app I've been working on uses Flask-User and their suggested models for authorization control. Here's an example:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # User Authentication information
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, default='')

    # User Email information
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())

    # User information
    is_enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False)


    # Relationships
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles',
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

class Role(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

class UserRoles(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

In addition, as part of the Flask-User/Flask-Login, `current_user` gives me a `User` object corresponding to the current user of the app (if logged in) and, as defined in our model, `current_user.roles` returns a list of `Role` objects, corresponding to the roles that are bound to the current user by the `UserRoles` table.

Now, at some point, I want to be able to query all users that have any of the roles the current user has. How can that be achieved given our `current_user.roles` list and my models in SQL Alchemy? How can I select all user where `any` of its `User.roles` match any of our `current_user.roles`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `__repr__` to Role as follows:

```
class Role(db.Model):

    #...

    def __repr__(self):

        return self.id
```

And you can use following query to achieve your requirement.

```
User.query.filter(User.roles.any(Role.id.in_([role.id for role in current_user.roles]))).all()
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and got the following error on the query `ArgumentError: Object 1 is not legal as a SQL literal value` on the `in` operation.